# Jboss5.1.x---Apache 2.2.22 Integration-Service Temporarily Unavailable(503 304) -Response

Tags: apache, jboss, integration, jboss5.x

I am using Jboss 5.1.x , Apache 2.2.22 and Mod_jk.so(1.2.37) . When i am trying to integrate between apache and jboss i am getting followed log in access.log and error.log files.

access.log:-

---

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013:12:48:10 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013:12:48:11 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013:12:48:14 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013:12:48:15 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013:12:48:19 +0530] "GET /sample HTTP/1.1" 503 323
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013:12:48:20 +0530] "GET /sample HTTP/1.1" 503 323
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013:12:48:24 +0530] "GET /sample HTTP/1.1" 503 323
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013:12:48:25 +0530] "GET /sample HTTP/1.1" 503 323
```

### Error.log :-

```
 [Sat Sep 07 12:46:34 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) mod_jk/1.2.37 configured -- resuming normal operations
 [Sat Sep 07 12:46:34 2013] [notice] Server built: Jan 28 2012 11:16:39
 [Sat Sep 07 12:46:34 2013] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4864
 [Sat Sep 07 12:46:34 2013] [notice] Child 4864: Child process is running
 [Sat Sep 07 12:46:34 2013] [notice] Child 4864: Acquired the start mutex.
 [Sat Sep 07 12:46:34 2013] [notice] Child 4864: Starting 64 worker threads.
 [Sat Sep 07 12:46:34 2013] [notice] Child 4864: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

### Error.log :-

```
[Sat Sep 07 12:46:34 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) mod_jk/1.2.37 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Sep 07 12:46:34 2013] [notice] Server built: Jan 28 2012 11:16:39
[Sat Sep 07 12:46:34 2013] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4864
[Sat Sep 07 12:46:34 2013] [notice] Child 4864: Child process is running
[Sat Sep 07 12:46:34 2013] [notice] Child 4864: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sat Sep 07 12:46:34 2013] [notice] Child 4864: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sat Sep 07 12:46:34 2013] [notice] Child 4864: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

I am using followed configuration files in apache side.

### Mod-jk.conf:-

```
LoadModule jk_module modules\mod_jk.so

JkWorkersFile conf\workers.properties
JkMountFile conf\uriworkermap.properties


JkLogFile conf\mod.jklog
JkLogLevel error
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
JkShmFile conf\mod.jkshm

JkMount /jkstatus/* jkstatus

JKMount /servlet* loadbalancer
JKMount /sample* loadbalancer
```

### workers.prop:-

```
# Workers

worker.jkstatus.type=status
worker.jkstatus.read_only=True

worker.node-1.port=8109
worker.node-1.host=localhost
worker.node-1.type=ajp13
worker.node-1.lbfactor=1
worker.node-1.socket_timeout=5
worker.node-1.socket_keepalive=1
worker.node-1.connection_pool_timeout=300
worker.node-1.connection_pool_size=20

worker.node-2.port=8209
worker.node-2.host=localhost
worker.node-2.type=ajp13
worker.node-2.lbfactor=1
worker.node-2.socket_timeout=5
worker.node-2.socket_keepalive=1
worker.node-2.connection_pool_timeout=300
worker.node-2.connection_pool_size=20

# Load-balancing pools

worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=node-1,node-2,
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=1

# Worker list
worker.list=loadbalancer,jkstatus
```

---->

When i am trying to access with localhost/sample request i am getting follwed response from browser window.

```
Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

Could you tell me how to solve the above issue ?

Thanks and Regards,
Narayan.

Answer (score 1):

I think that error occurs because of mod_jk. Although that error occurs, you can call your web application via apache server.

Usually, we use AJP connector to integrate Apache to Jboss with port(8009).
So, you have to pass your web application address at etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy_ajp.conf like
ProxyPass /mywebapp/ ajp://jbossserverip:8009/mywebapp/

From your browser, type your apache server address apacherserveripaddress/mywebapp/